# Automated suggestion tool

Tags: c#, .net, unit-tests

After a long road with Randoop.NET as a unit test suggestion tool, my developing team has decided to upgrade to a commercial tool which will provide us a full unit testing framework for professional TDD workflow.

- super important for it to include a well-performing runner AND a mocking framework, the coverage part is less relevant but can be an advantage.
- must be super user-friendly and easy to manage but yet powerful and efficient.

P.S - 
We work on VS2017 with .net framework

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been using [Typemock's Isolator](https://www.typemock.com/isolator-product-page/) for a few years and it works really well. I think it fits your needs because:

- it is a full unit testing framework
- it has a feature called "suggest", that creates test suggestions automatically
- it has a test runner
- it includes a mocking framework
- it has a coverage tool
- it integrates with VS2017